# Radiometric quantities and time in rendering

Tags: physics, rendering

Often in papers people use various radiometric quantities, mostly radiant flux, radiant intensity, radiance and irradiance.

It seems to me that all of these quantities are dependent on time. For example, radiant flux is defined as the amount of radiant energy per span of time (emitted by a light source). The other quantities contain radiant flux in some measure so they seem to depend on time as well.

Yet when reading papers, people don't go into time at all. For example, some papers say "the radiant flux diffusely reflected by this area of the surface is x" and then they go on to explain that x is just light_colored_intensity * surface_color or something (depending on the illumination model used, of course), not factoring in any kind of time at all.

Is this because the time frames observed are assumed to be 1 second? Is the time factored out somewhere (perhaps when defining the light intensity, which may be defined as radiant flux)? What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Also I know it's Christmas Eve in many places, but dinner time is long past, my family is boring and I'm bored, so I have nothing better to do than to read through some rendering papers. Don't judge :)

Comment: As the render time ("exposure time" if you like) can vary quite a bit from frame to frame, figuring it into the lighting equation would make each frame vary in luminance, not a desirable effect I imagine. You could get rid of that by dividing the resulting luminance by the exposure time (which would just cancel the exposure time out again), or by applying proper photographic exposure/tone mapping to each frame, figuring in the exposure time again.

Comment: So in the end you'd figure it in, just to cancel it out again, wasted effort and processing time - both are precious :) Also, when you're "just" rendering (real-time, offline, even "physically accurate"), you usually don't care about cases where time passes at a different rates than 1 second per second. I'm totally guessing here, but that's why it's not an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is involved in radiometric quantities fundamentally because light is always moving, flowing through space.  It's like describing traffic on a road - the relevant quantity is usually not the number of cars on the road, but number of cars that pass a given point per unit time.  Or think of water flowing through a pipe, which you'd measure in volume per unit time.  Light is energy flowing through space and gets measured in the form of power (watts), which is energy per unit time.

Suppose you look at a "static" scene - no lights or objects are moving, no pixel values are changing on screen.  The light in the scene is not static; it's just in radiative equilibrium.  Light energy is constantly being emitted from all the light sources in the scene, and constantly being reflected, scattered, and absorbed by all the surfaces and media in the scene.  What is static is the rate of each of these energy flows, i.e. their power.  In any given region, the power of incoming light equals the power of outgoing and absorbed light, so the amount of light is not changing over time.  This includes your eyeballs or your video camera - you see a steady image because the amount of light arriving per unit time is constant.

When you switch the lights on in a room, it takes some time for it to come to this equilibrium, but that happens in just microseconds due to the speed of light.  So in rendering we typically assume the scene is always in radiative equilibrium - even if the scene is changing, it's usually not changing significantly on the scale of microseconds.  Rendering algorithms try to calculate that equilibrium, so they naturally work in units of the flow of energy (power) rather than energy itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all these radiometric quantities should be considered per unit of time. But no, they are not summed over 1 second. In theory, the **radiant flux should be integrated over the whole frame length** (*e.g.* 1/60 seconds) in order to compute the **radiant energy** sent to the viewer’s eye during that frame length. However, such an integration is usually too complex to compute accurately.

The most common approximation is to simulate a camera with an infinitely fast [shutter speed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutter_speed), meaning the whole scene is static. In this case, there is no need to integrate the flux: it is considered constant (that’s why your papers use intensity and flux instead of energy). Then if you want to know the approximate energy received during the frame, you simply multiply the final flux by the frame length.

Another method is to perform multiple renderings of the frame, at regularly spaced intervals, and compute their average. This leads to the effect known as [motion blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_blur). Mathematically, it is akin to integrating the radiant flux using the [rectangle method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method).

In the end, it does not matter *much* whether the data stored in an image is the radiant flux or the radiant energy. But I think it’s more mathematically rigourous to:

- perform light computations for a single, instantaneous frame, using flux and intensity values (*i.e.* per unit of time)
- consider the data in the final image is an energy value, because when *e.g.* motion blur has been applied, the instantaneity of the frame is lost.